# Problem with resetting Screen Resolution using cron job

Tags: display, reboot, settings

I am running a cron job with `@ reboot bin/sleep 60 /path/to/script`. I know the job runs 60 seconds after reboot but I get an error. The script is:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1440_60.00
sudo xrandr --output  HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
```

The error output is:

```
Can't open display
Can't open display
Can't open display
```

The script is supposed to reset the screen output resolution as I am accessing the Pi4 via VNC on my 5K 27" iMac. When I run the script from the terminal via VNC it just does everything fine. I should mention that due to my setup I do not get a pwd challenge when using sudo so when I just run the script from the CLI it runs and changes the display output without pwd challenge.
What can I do to make this work in the cron job?
Many thanks for any help!
Hans

Comment: Why do you want to use a cron when it is simpler to just set default resolution in config.txt?

Answer (score 1):

How does the cronjob know what display this refers to? Cron does not inherit any X11 environment.

The display that is used by X11 is found in the variable `DISPLAY`. For example, I might get:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

But in your cronjob, `$DISPLAY` is empty.

A cronjob is not the place where you do this.

If the set-up is specific for your session, you woud typically put it in `~/.xinitrc`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't know that a cronjob can't figure out what display I am using. I am obviously very new to this so I find it difficult to understand why a script run manually vs. cronjob should have different "knowledge" of the environment. In any case, I'll investigate ~/.xinitrc. I have tried /etc/rc.local and other options I found online to run a script at boot but it seems that most options run too early and there is even less "awareness" of the environment.